# How to redirect users to customized page depending on input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**I am just starting out with JavaScript. Pardon me for posting the whole code here. Since someone just suggested of posting a full code, I am doing it, as I am eager to get this right.**

I am trying to redirect users to customized "Thank you page", depending on their area, upon submission of a page. Like you see, there are many forms and I am trying to find out their province by their areacode. As I am very new to javascript. I would like to ask you some help on this.

What I am basically trying to do is show users different "Thank you page". *Imagine a page saying Thank you, your local rep in British Columbia will contact you.*

So this is my attempt, which currently doesn't work and I can't find why.

```
     <!--=== Content Part ===-->
  <div class="container content">
    <div class="title-box">
      <div class="title-box-text"><span class="color-green">Book a Demo</span></div>
      <p>With ClearDent, you can do everything. Better.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Content Blocks -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Homework for Jason Begin -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <!-- Homework for Jason End -->
        <form id="sfDemoForm" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="sky-form">
          <input name="captcha_settings" value="{&quot;keyname&quot;:&quot;IC_ClearDent_Main_Demo&quot;,&quot;fallback&quot;:&quot;true&quot;,&quot;orgId&quot;:&quot;00D1I0000002QyG&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" type="hidden">
          <input name="oid" value="00D1I0000002QyG" type="hidden">
          <input name="retURL" value="https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou.html" type="hidden">

          <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  --> 
          <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    --> 
          <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          --> 
          <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              --> 
          <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="ppli@cleardent.com">      --> 
          <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

          <fieldset>
            <!--<label class="label" for="first_name">First Name</label>-->
            <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
              <input  id="sffirst_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="First name">
            </label>
            <!--<label class="label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>-->
            <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
              <input  id="sflast_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Last name">
            </label>
            <!--<label class="label" for="email">Email</label>-->
            <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
              <input id="sfemail" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" required placeholder="Email address">
            </label>
            <!-- <label class="label" for="phone">Phone</label>-->
            <label class="input margin-bottom-25"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
              <input id="sfphone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Phone">
            </label>
            <!--<label class="label" for="description">Notes</label>-->
            <label class="textarea textarea-resizable margin-bottom-25">
              <textarea id="sfdescription" name="description" placeholder="Is there something specific you want to see from ClearDent?"></textarea>
            </label>
            <input id="sfstate" name="state" type="hidden">
            <input id="sflead_source" name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="Website">
            <input id="sfcompany" name="company" type="hidden">
            <input id="sfCampaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="7011I000000d5auQAA">
          </fieldset>
          <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeXmEAUAAAAAG7VJd6Z8YCVkP44AgAlqCUmpRAi" data-callback="submitDemoToLead" data-size="invisible"> </div>
          <footer>
            <button id="sfdemoPreSubmit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Get Your Free Demo</button>
            <!--<button class="btn-u btn-brd" onclick="window.history.back();"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i> Back</button>--> 
          </footer>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content Blocks --> 

  </div>
  <!--=== End Content ===--> 

  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> 

  <!--=== Footer Version 1 ===-->
  <div class="footer-v1">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
          <!-- Social -->
          <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="../">
                <div class="logo"> </div>
                </a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>Subscribe to ClearDent Newsletter</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup" class="row margin-bottom-20">
              <form action="//cleardent.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c94a01df02408fee7e80ba656&amp;id=3d0b9b204d&amp;MERGE3=Web" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="form-inline" target="_blank">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email address</label>
                    <span class="input-group-addon colour-cleardent"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn-u form-control">Subscribe</button>
                    </span> </div>
                </div>
                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                  <input type="text" name="b_c94a01df02408fee7e80ba656_3d0b9b204d" tabindex="-1" value="">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="headline">
                  <h2>Connect With Us</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="social-connect">
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-rss" onclick="window.open('http://marketing.cleardent.com/')"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-rss"></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/ClearDentSoftware')"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/ClearDentCanada')"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-googleplus" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/+CleardentCanada/?prsrc=3')"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/col-md-3--> 
          <!-- End Social --> 

          <!-- Badge -->
          <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="posts">
              <div class="headline">
                <h2>Seal of Approval</h2>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-unstyled latest-list">
                <li> <a href="iso-certification-and-academy-of-general-dentistry-approval.html" id="footer-2-iso">
                  <div class="iso-logo"></div>
                  </a><small class="iso-logo-text">FM584056</small></li>
                <li> <a href="iso-certification-and-academy-of-general-dentistry-approval.html" id="footer-2-agd">
                  <div class="agd-logo"></div>
                  </a><small class="agd-logo-text">1/4/2017 - 31/3/2019 | AGD Provider ID: 32124</small></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/col-md-3--> 
          <!-- End Badge --> 

          <!-- Link List -->
          <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="headline">
              <h2>Popular Pages</h2>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled link-list">
              <li><a href="../" id="footer-2-home">Features</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
              <li><a href="marketing/" id="footer-2-blog">Blog</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
              <li><a href="support/" id="footer-2-support">Support</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
              <li><a href="free-tools/training-videos.php" id="footer-2-videos">Training Videos</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
              <li><a href="events/" id="footer-2-events">Events</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/col-md-3--> 
          <!-- End Link List --> 

          <!-- Address -->
          <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="contact-info-area">
              <div class="contact-info">
                <div class="headline">
                  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                </div>
                <address>
                166-5489 Byrne Road<br>
                Burnaby BC<br>
                Canada V5J 3J1
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="addr-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></td>
                    <td class="addr-list-text"><a href="tel:+18662532748" id="footer-2-phone">1-866-253-2748</a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="addr-icon"><i class="fa fa-fax"></i></td>
                    <td class="addr-list-text"><a href="fax:+18666110548" id="footer-2-fax">1-866-611-0548</a> (Fax)</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="addr-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></td>
                    <td class="addr-list-text"><a href="mailto:info@cleardent.com" id="footer-2-email">info@cleardent.com</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </address>
              </div>
              <div class="map-img"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/col-md-3--> 
          <!-- End Address --> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/footer-->

    <div class="copyright">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>&copy; ClearDent | <a href="privacy.html" id="footer-2-privacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
          </div>
          <!-- Social Share Links -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="social-icons pull-right">
              <p>Share this page:
                <button class="btn btn-sm rounded-4x btn-facebook" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=211125742252409&amp;display=popup&amp;href=' + encodeURI(window.location.href) + '&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cleardent.com%2F')"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm rounded-4x btn-twitter" onClick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=cleardentcanada&amp;url=' + encodeURI(window.location.href))"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm rounded-4x btn-googleplus" onClick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURI(window.location.href))"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Social Share Links --> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/copyright--> 
  <!--=== End Footer Version 1 ===--> 
</div>
<!--/wrapper--> 
<!-- Demo Request Success Message -->
<div id="demoSuccessMsg" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="alertdialog" aria-labelledby="demoSuccessLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="alert">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></button>
        <h4 id="demoSuccessLabel" class="modal-title">Demo Request Sent!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Thank you. A ClearDent consultant will contact you via the contact information you have just provided within two (2) business days.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Got it!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Google Optimize Popup Modal -->
<div id="modalConvert" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="labelConvert">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"> <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="convertPopup-GoogleOptimize-plugin" -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></button>
        <h4 id="labelConvert" class="modal-title">Like what you see? See even more!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> <img class="img-responsive img-spacer margin-bottom-30" src="assets/img/features/cleardent/kiosk.png" alt="iPad Kiosk helps with gathering patient in-take">
        <p>Book a demo and one of our friendly consultants can walk you through all the benefits your practice can expect when you choose to implement Kiosk at your practice. Plus, we have many other amazing features that we would be happy to show you as well!</p>
        <!-- Demo Menu-->
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demo-formPopup" name="demo-formPopup" class="sky-form" onSubmit="return false;">
          <fieldset>
            <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="demo-name" id="demo-namePopup" required placeholder="Your name">
            </label>
            <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
              <input type="email" name="demo-email" id="demo-emailPopup" required placeholder="Your email">
            </label>
            <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
              <input type="tel" name="demo-phone" id="demo-phonePopup" required placeholder="Your phone number">
            </label>
            <label class="input"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-commenting"></i>
              <input type="text" name="demo-notes" placeholder="Additional notes to us">
            </label>
            <input class="hidden" type="text" id="n7Q2326JYZ334s58FWq3TrPopup" name="n7Q2326JYZ334s58FWq3Tr" value="bg62U79DPNCTbBvpZHueZG" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <input class="hidden" type="text" id="campaignPopup" name="campaign" value="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
          </fieldset>
          <footer>
            <div class="form-buttons">
              <button id="btnReqDemoPopup" class="btn-u pull-left"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Book</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-brd pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-sub-msg">
              <p>Sending a demo request, please wait&hellip;</p>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Google Optimize Popup Modal End --> 
<!-- JS Global Compulsory
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.4.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
--> 
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins
<script src="../assets/1.9.5/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smoothscroll/1.4.6/SmoothScroll.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script> 
--> 
<script src="assets/1.9.7/assets/js/all-page-pack/js/all-page-pack.min.js"></script> 
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="page-linked-script" --> <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> 
<!-- JS Main
<script src="../assets/1.9.5/js/plugins/fancy-box.js"></script> 
<script src="../assets/1.9.5/js/app.js"></script>
--> 
<!-- JS Customization 
<script src="../assets/1.9.5/js/custom2.js"></script>
--> 
<script src="assets/1.9.7/assets/js/all-page-pack/js/custom-pack.min.js"></script> 
<!-- JS Page Level --> 
<script>
function parse_query_string(query) {
  var vars = query.split("&");
  var query_string = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [query_string[pair[0]], decodeURIComponent(pair[1])];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
      // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  }
  return query_string;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    App.init(); 

    FancyBox.initFancybox();

    wow = new WOW().init();

    $("#demo-phone").mask('(999) 999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});

    $("#demo-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
      var query_str = parse_query_string(window.location.search.substring(1));
      if (typeof(query_str) || typeof(query_str["utm_campaign"])) {
        $("#campaign").val(query_str["utm_campaign"]);
      } else {
        $("#campaign").val("Not Specified");
      }      
            ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demo.php");
            $(".form-buttons").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".form-sub-msg").fadeIn("fast");
            $.fancybox.showLoading();
            $.post("/script/demo.php", $("#demo-form").serialize(), function(data) {
                if (data.indexOf("Failed") == -1) {
                    try {
                        ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demoed.php");
                    /*  fbq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: 1.00,
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"] 
                        });                     
                        twq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: "1.00",
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"],
                          num_items: 1
                        });     */          
                    } catch (e) {}
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    $(".form-sub-msg").fadeOut("fast");
                    $(".form-buttons").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#btnClear").click();
                    $("#demoSuccessMsg").modal("show");
                } else {
                    $(".form-sub-msg").html("<strong style='color: red;'>Error sending request, please call <a href='tel:+18662532748,1'>1-866-253-2748</a>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</strong>");
                }
            });
        }
    });

  //Pop-up conversion plugin for Google Optimize
  $("#demo-phonePopup").mask('(999) 999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});

    $("#demo-formPopup").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
      var query_str = parse_query_string(window.location.search.substring(1));
      if (typeof(query_str) || typeof(query_str["utm_campaign"])) {
        $("#campaignPopup").val(query_str["utm_campaign"]);
      } else {
        $("#campaignPopup").val("Not Specified");
      }
            ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demo.php");
            $(".form-buttons").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".form-sub-msg").fadeIn("fast");
            $.fancybox.showLoading();      
            $.post("/script/demo.php", $("#demo-formPopup").serialize(), function(data) {
                if (data.indexOf("Failed") == -1) {
                    try {
                        ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demoed.php");
                        fbq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: 1.00,
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"] 
                        });                     
                        twq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: "1.00",
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"],
                          num_items: 1
                        });                     
                    } catch (e) {}
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    $(".form-sub-msg").fadeOut("fast");
                    $(".form-buttons").fadeIn("fast");                  
          $('#modalConvert').modal("hide")
                    $("#demoSuccessMsg").modal("show");
                } else {
                    $(".form-sub-msg").html("<strong style='color: red;'>Error sending request, please call <a href='tel:+18662532748,1'>1-866-253-2748</a>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</strong>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script> 
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="page-script" --> 
<!--Facebook Advanced Matching Start--> 
<!-- Homework for Jason Begin (Wrong Use Here; Use Cookie to send successful submit to thank you page) -->
<!--<script>
/*
fbq('init', '697649880319954', { 
em: '{{_email_}}',
ph: '{{_phone_}}',
}); 
*/
</script> -->
<!-- Homework for Jason End -->
<!--Facebook Advanced Matching End--> 
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script> 
<script>  
  //Required Salesforce functions
  function timestamp() {
    var response = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response");
    if (response == null || response.value.trim() == "") {
      var elems = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value);
      elems["ts"] = JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime());
      document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value = JSON.stringify(elems);
    }
  }
  window.setInterval(timestamp, 500); 

  //Masking
  $("#sfphone").mask('(999) 999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});

  //Form helper functions
  function getProvince(pStrPhone) {
    var areacode = pStrPhone.substring(0, 3);
    switch (areacode) {
      case "403":
      case "780":
      case "587":
      case "825":
        return "AB";
      case "604":
      case "778":
      case "250":
      case "236":
        return "BC";
            window.location.replace('page1.html');
            break;
      case "204":
      case "431":
        return "MB";
      case "506":
        return "NB";
      case "709":
        return "NL";
      case "867":
        return "YT";
      case "902":
      case "782":
        return "NS";
      case "416":
      case "647":
      case "437":
      case "519":
      case "226":
      case "548":
      case "613":
      case "343":
      case "705":
      case "249":
      case "807":
      case "905":
      case "289":
      case "365":
        return "ON";
      case "418":
      case "581":
      case "450":
      case "579":
      case "514":
      case "438":
      case "819":
      case "873":
        return "QC";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }  

  function cleanPhNum(pStrPhone) {
    return pStrPhone.replace("-", "").replace("(", "").replace(")","").replace(" ", "");
  }
  //Form validation and reCAPTCHA
    //Jason Home Work - jQuery Validate and figure out how it validates
  $("#sfdemoPreSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sfcompany").val($("#sflast_name").val() + ", " + $("#sffirst_name").val());
    $("#sfphone").val(cleanPhNum($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfstate").val(getProvince($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfDemoForm").validate();
    if ($("#sfDemoForm").valid()) {
       grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  });

  function submitDemoToLead(token) {
    $("#sfDemoForm").submit();  
  }

function redirect() {
    var textValue = areacode;
    if(textValue == 'BC')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/bc";
    }
    if(textValue == 'AB')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/ab";
    }
    if(textValue == 'ON')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/on";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid Input");
    }
}

  /*
    $("#sfDemoForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {      
      var query_str = parse_query_string(window.location.search.substring(1));
      if (typeof(query_str) || typeof(query_str["utm_campaign"])) {
        $("#campaign").val(query_str["utm_campaign"]);
      } else {
        $("#campaign").val("Not Specified");
      }      
            ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demo.php");
            $(".form-buttons").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".form-sub-msg").fadeIn("fast");
            $.fancybox.showLoading();
            $.post("/script/demo.php", $("#demo-form").serialize(), function(data) {
                if (data.indexOf("Failed") == -1) {
                    try {
                        ga("send", "pageview", "/script/demoed.php");
                        fbq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: 1.00,
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"] 
                        });                     
                        twq("track", "Purchase", {
                          value: "1.00",
                          currency: "CAD",
                          content_type: "product",
                          content_ids: ["1"],
                          num_items: 1
                        });                     
                    } catch (e) {}
                    $.fancybox.hideLoading();
                    $(".form-sub-msg").fadeOut("fast");
                    $(".form-buttons").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#btnClear").click();
                    $("#demoSuccessMsg").modal("show");
                } else {
                    $(".form-sub-msg").html("<strong style='color: red;'>Error sending request, please call <a href='tel:+18662532748,1'>1-866-253-2748</a>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</strong>");
                }  
            });      
        }
    });
  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, it is best to post only the portions of code that are relevant to your specific question.

In regards to your question, read up on **[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location#Methods)**

You'll want to add something similar to this in the success callback of your `$.post`:

```
window.location.href = "http://yourwebsite.com/thank_you.html";
```